# How to find the size of an svg programatically?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a number of svg files of different components.  Each of these components may or may not contain "port"'s which I want to ignore when determining the size of the svg.  For example here are 2 different kinds of svg's that I have:

```
<svg width="263" height="203" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g class="component">
        <polygon points="41.5,201.5 241.5,201.5 241.5,1.5 41.5,1.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polyline points="41.5,41.5 67.5,77.5 97.5,77.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polyline points="41.5,161.5 67.5,129.5 99.5,129.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polygon points="191.5,101.5 191.3,97.2 190.8,92.9 189.8,88.7 188.6,84.6 186.9,80.6 185.0,76.8 182.7,73.2 180.1,69.7 177.2,66.5 174.1,63.6 170.7,60.9 167.1,58.6 163.3,56.5 159.4,54.8 155.3,53.4 151.1,52.4 146.9,51.8 142.6,51.5 138.3,51.6 134.0,52.1 129.8,52.9 125.6,54.1 121.6,55.6 117.8,57.5 114.1,59.7 110.6,62.2 107.3,65.0 104.3,68.1 101.6,71.4 99.1,75.0 97.0,78.7 95.2,82.6 93.8,86.7 92.7,90.8 91.9,95.1 91.5,99.3 91.5,103.7 91.9,107.9 92.7,112.2 93.8,116.3 95.2,120.4 97.0,124.3 99.1,128.0 101.6,131.6 104.3,134.9 107.3,138.0 110.6,140.8 114.1,143.3 117.8,145.5 121.6,147.4 125.6,148.9 129.8,150.1 134.0,150.9 138.3,151.4 142.6,151.5 146.9,151.2 151.1,150.6 155.3,149.6 159.4,148.2 163.3,146.5 167.1,144.4 170.7,142.1 174.1,139.4 177.2,136.5 180.1,133.3 182.7,129.8 185.0,126.2 186.9,122.4 188.6,118.4 189.8,114.3 190.8,110.1 191.3,105.8" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polyline points="191.5,101.5 241.5,101.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <text x="141.5" y="133.8" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="90.3px" font-family="sans-serif">+</text>
        <text x="94.0" y="48.7" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="53.1px" font-family="sans-serif">1</text>
        <text x="94.0" y="192.7" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="53.1px" font-family="sans-serif">1</text>
        <g id="u1" class="port">
            <polygon points="1.5,21.5 41.5,41.5 1.5,61.5" fill="#00007F" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </g>
        <g id="u2" class="port">
            <polygon points="1.5,141.5 41.5,161.5 1.5,181.5" fill="#00007F" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </g>
        <g id="y" class="port">
            <polygon points="241.5,91.5 261.5,101.5 241.5,111.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg width="223" height="203" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g class="component">
        <polygon points="1.5,201.5 201.5,201.5 201.5,1.5 1.5,1.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polyline points="21.5,33.5 21.5,181.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polygon points="21.5,11.5 13.5,33.5 29.5,33.5" fill="#C0C0C0" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polyline points="11.5,101.5 169.5,101.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polygon points="191.5,101.5 169.5,93.5 169.5,109.5" fill="#C0C0C0" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polyline points="21.5,101.5 27.2,84.4 30.7,73.8 33.8,65.0 36.4,57.8 36.4,57.8 38.2,53.3 39.9,49.1 41.6,45.2 43.2,41.8 43.2,41.8 44.5,39.2 45.7,36.8 46.9,34.7 48.1,32.7 49.2,31.0 49.2,31.0 50.7,29.1 52.1,27.4 53.5,25.9 54.9,24.6 54.9,24.6 56.8,23.4 58.6,22.5 60.5,22.0 60.5,22.0 62.4,22.0 64.2,22.5 66.1,23.3 66.1,23.3 67.5,24.2 68.9,25.4 70.3,26.7 71.8,28.4 71.8,28.4 72.9,29.8 74.0,31.4 75.2,33.1 76.3,35.0 77.4,37.0 77.4,37.0 78.8,39.7 80.3,42.7 81.8,46.1 83.4,49.8 83.4,49.8 85.6,55.3 88.0,61.6 90.6,68.8 90.6,68.8 93.8,78.1 98.0,90.6 103.1,106.3 103.1,106.3 108.2,121.8 112.3,133.7 115.2,142.0 115.2,142.0 117.0,146.7 118.7,151.0 120.4,155.0 122.0,158.7 122.0,158.7 123.3,161.4 124.5,163.9 125.7,166.2 126.9,168.3 128.0,170.2 128.0,170.2 129.4,172.3 130.8,174.2 132.2,175.8 133.6,177.2 133.6,177.2 135.5,178.8 137.4,180.0 139.3,180.7 139.3,180.7 141.2,181.0 143.0,180.9 144.9,180.3 144.9,180.3 146.8,179.3 148.7,177.9 150.6,176.0 150.6,176.0 152.0,174.4 153.4,172.6 154.8,170.5 156.2,168.2 156.2,168.2 157.3,166.2 158.5,164.0 159.7,161.5 160.9,158.9 162.2,156.0 162.2,156.0 164.4,150.7 166.8,144.5 169.4,137.5 169.4,137.5 172.1,129.9 174.8,122.0 177.5,113.9 181.5,101.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <g id="y" class="port">
            <polygon points="201.5,91.5 221.5,101.5 201.5,111.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

After loading the svg's into my HTML, is there a way to calculate the size of each of these svg images while ignoring any "port" objects that may be contained in each file?  The width and height properties defined in the svg tag tells me the size of the entire image, but I want to know the size of the image without the ports.  Also I'd like to be able to know what is the offset from the top left corner of the size of the image without the ports.  ie if there is no port on the left side then the offset would be 0, if there was a port on the left side then the offset would be equal to the width taken up by the port on the left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did a bit of preprocessing, and organised your svg components into two groups - "body" and "ports" - you could do something like this:

```js
// For each SVG, call the getBBoxWithoutPort() function.
document.querySelectorAll('svg').forEach(function(svg) {
  console.log(getBBoxWithoutPort(svg));
});

function getBBoxWithoutPort(el) {
  // get a reference to the body group
  var body = el.querySelector('.body');
  // Return its size
  return body.getBBox();
}
```

```html
<svg width="263" height="203" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g class="component">
        <g class="body">
            <polygon points="41.5,201.5 241.5,201.5 241.5,1.5 41.5,1.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <polyline points="41.5,41.5 67.5,77.5 97.5,77.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <polyline points="41.5,161.5 67.5,129.5 99.5,129.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <polygon points="191.5,101.5 191.3,97.2 190.8,92.9 189.8,88.7 188.6,84.6 186.9,80.6 185.0,76.8 182.7,73.2 180.1,69.7 177.2,66.5 174.1,63.6 170.7,60.9 167.1,58.6 163.3,56.5 159.4,54.8 155.3,53.4 151.1,52.4 146.9,51.8 142.6,51.5 138.3,51.6 134.0,52.1 129.8,52.9 125.6,54.1 121.6,55.6 117.8,57.5 114.1,59.7 110.6,62.2 107.3,65.0 104.3,68.1 101.6,71.4 99.1,75.0 97.0,78.7 95.2,82.6 93.8,86.7 92.7,90.8 91.9,95.1 91.5,99.3 91.5,103.7 91.9,107.9 92.7,112.2 93.8,116.3 95.2,120.4 97.0,124.3 99.1,128.0 101.6,131.6 104.3,134.9 107.3,138.0 110.6,140.8 114.1,143.3 117.8,145.5 121.6,147.4 125.6,148.9 129.8,150.1 134.0,150.9 138.3,151.4 142.6,151.5 146.9,151.2 151.1,150.6 155.3,149.6 159.4,148.2 163.3,146.5 167.1,144.4 170.7,142.1 174.1,139.4 177.2,136.5 180.1,133.3 182.7,129.8 185.0,126.2 186.9,122.4 188.6,118.4 189.8,114.3 190.8,110.1 191.3,105.8" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <polyline points="191.5,101.5 241.5,101.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <text x="141.5" y="133.8" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="90.3px" font-family="sans-serif">+</text>
            <text x="94.0" y="48.7" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="53.1px" font-family="sans-serif">1</text>
            <text x="94.0" y="192.7" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="53.1px" font-family="sans-serif">1</text>
        </g>
        <g class="ports">
            <g id="u1" class="port">
                <polygon points="1.5,21.5 41.5,41.5 1.5,61.5" fill="#00007F" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            </g>
            <g id="u2" class="port">
                <polygon points="1.5,141.5 41.5,161.5 1.5,181.5" fill="#00007F" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            </g>
            <g id="y" class="port">
                <polygon points="241.5,91.5 261.5,101.5 241.5,111.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg width="223" height="203" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g class="component">
        <g class="body">
            <polygon points="1.5,201.5 201.5,201.5 201.5,1.5 1.5,1.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <polyline points="21.5,33.5 21.5,181.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <polygon points="21.5,11.5 13.5,33.5 29.5,33.5" fill="#C0C0C0" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <polyline points="11.5,101.5 169.5,101.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <polygon points="191.5,101.5 169.5,93.5 169.5,109.5" fill="#C0C0C0" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <polyline points="21.5,101.5 27.2,84.4 30.7,73.8 33.8,65.0 36.4,57.8 36.4,57.8 38.2,53.3 39.9,49.1 41.6,45.2 43.2,41.8 43.2,41.8 44.5,39.2 45.7,36.8 46.9,34.7 48.1,32.7 49.2,31.0 49.2,31.0 50.7,29.1 52.1,27.4 53.5,25.9 54.9,24.6 54.9,24.6 56.8,23.4 58.6,22.5 60.5,22.0 60.5,22.0 62.4,22.0 64.2,22.5 66.1,23.3 66.1,23.3 67.5,24.2 68.9,25.4 70.3,26.7 71.8,28.4 71.8,28.4 72.9,29.8 74.0,31.4 75.2,33.1 76.3,35.0 77.4,37.0 77.4,37.0 78.8,39.7 80.3,42.7 81.8,46.1 83.4,49.8 83.4,49.8 85.6,55.3 88.0,61.6 90.6,68.8 90.6,68.8 93.8,78.1 98.0,90.6 103.1,106.3 103.1,106.3 108.2,121.8 112.3,133.7 115.2,142.0 115.2,142.0 117.0,146.7 118.7,151.0 120.4,155.0 122.0,158.7 122.0,158.7 123.3,161.4 124.5,163.9 125.7,166.2 126.9,168.3 128.0,170.2 128.0,170.2 129.4,172.3 130.8,174.2 132.2,175.8 133.6,177.2 133.6,177.2 135.5,178.8 137.4,180.0 139.3,180.7 139.3,180.7 141.2,181.0 143.0,180.9 144.9,180.3 144.9,180.3 146.8,179.3 148.7,177.9 150.6,176.0 150.6,176.0 152.0,174.4 153.4,172.6 154.8,170.5 156.2,168.2 156.2,168.2 157.3,166.2 158.5,164.0 159.7,161.5 160.9,158.9 162.2,156.0 162.2,156.0 164.4,150.7 166.8,144.5 169.4,137.5 169.4,137.5 172.1,129.9 174.8,122.0 177.5,113.9 181.5,101.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </g>
        <g class="ports">
            <g id="y" class="port">
                <polygon points="201.5,91.5 221.5,101.5 201.5,111.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: That is a very good idea, it saves me from having to manipulate the DOM

Comment: Yours would still be a valid approach if the files weren't modifiable :)

Answer (score 1):

You can

- iterate through your svg elements,
- remove their children that you don't want,
- get the svg's BBox,
- re-append the removed elements where they were.

**ES6 implementation** would require transpiling or complete rewrite for ES5 browsers.

```js
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll('svg')]
    .map(getBBoxWithoutPort)
);

function getBBoxWithoutPort(el) {
  // grab all the .port elements and store in an Array
  const ports = [...el.querySelectorAll('.port')];
  ports.forEach(p => {
    // store their parentNode and nextSibling
    p._parent = p.parentNode;
    p._next = p.nextElementSibling;
    // remove it from the DOM
    p.remove();
  });
  // now get the size of the parent SVG node
  const size = el.getBBox();
  ports.forEach(p => {
    // re-append your removed elements
    p._parent.insertBefore(p, (p._next && p._next.parentNode) ? p._next : null);
    // clean
    delete p._parent;
    delete p._next;
  });
  return size;
}
```

```html
<svg width="263" height="203" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g class="component">
        <polygon points="41.5,201.5 241.5,201.5 241.5,1.5 41.5,1.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polyline points="41.5,41.5 67.5,77.5 97.5,77.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polyline points="41.5,161.5 67.5,129.5 99.5,129.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polygon points="191.5,101.5 191.3,97.2 190.8,92.9 189.8,88.7 188.6,84.6 186.9,80.6 185.0,76.8 182.7,73.2 180.1,69.7 177.2,66.5 174.1,63.6 170.7,60.9 167.1,58.6 163.3,56.5 159.4,54.8 155.3,53.4 151.1,52.4 146.9,51.8 142.6,51.5 138.3,51.6 134.0,52.1 129.8,52.9 125.6,54.1 121.6,55.6 117.8,57.5 114.1,59.7 110.6,62.2 107.3,65.0 104.3,68.1 101.6,71.4 99.1,75.0 97.0,78.7 95.2,82.6 93.8,86.7 92.7,90.8 91.9,95.1 91.5,99.3 91.5,103.7 91.9,107.9 92.7,112.2 93.8,116.3 95.2,120.4 97.0,124.3 99.1,128.0 101.6,131.6 104.3,134.9 107.3,138.0 110.6,140.8 114.1,143.3 117.8,145.5 121.6,147.4 125.6,148.9 129.8,150.1 134.0,150.9 138.3,151.4 142.6,151.5 146.9,151.2 151.1,150.6 155.3,149.6 159.4,148.2 163.3,146.5 167.1,144.4 170.7,142.1 174.1,139.4 177.2,136.5 180.1,133.3 182.7,129.8 185.0,126.2 186.9,122.4 188.6,118.4 189.8,114.3 190.8,110.1 191.3,105.8" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polyline points="191.5,101.5 241.5,101.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <text x="141.5" y="133.8" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="90.3px" font-family="sans-serif">+</text>
        <text x="94.0" y="48.7" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="53.1px" font-family="sans-serif">1</text>
        <text x="94.0" y="192.7" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="53.1px" font-family="sans-serif">1</text>
        <g id="u1" class="port">
            <polygon points="1.5,21.5 41.5,41.5 1.5,61.5" fill="#00007F" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </g>
        <g id="u2" class="port">
            <polygon points="1.5,141.5 41.5,161.5 1.5,181.5" fill="#00007F" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </g>
        <g id="y" class="port">
            <polygon points="241.5,91.5 261.5,101.5 241.5,111.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg width="223" height="203" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g class="component">
        <polygon points="1.5,201.5 201.5,201.5 201.5,1.5 1.5,1.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polyline points="21.5,33.5 21.5,181.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polygon points="21.5,11.5 13.5,33.5 29.5,33.5" fill="#C0C0C0" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polyline points="11.5,101.5 169.5,101.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polygon points="191.5,101.5 169.5,93.5 169.5,109.5" fill="#C0C0C0" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <polyline points="21.5,101.5 27.2,84.4 30.7,73.8 33.8,65.0 36.4,57.8 36.4,57.8 38.2,53.3 39.9,49.1 41.6,45.2 43.2,41.8 43.2,41.8 44.5,39.2 45.7,36.8 46.9,34.7 48.1,32.7 49.2,31.0 49.2,31.0 50.7,29.1 52.1,27.4 53.5,25.9 54.9,24.6 54.9,24.6 56.8,23.4 58.6,22.5 60.5,22.0 60.5,22.0 62.4,22.0 64.2,22.5 66.1,23.3 66.1,23.3 67.5,24.2 68.9,25.4 70.3,26.7 71.8,28.4 71.8,28.4 72.9,29.8 74.0,31.4 75.2,33.1 76.3,35.0 77.4,37.0 77.4,37.0 78.8,39.7 80.3,42.7 81.8,46.1 83.4,49.8 83.4,49.8 85.6,55.3 88.0,61.6 90.6,68.8 90.6,68.8 93.8,78.1 98.0,90.6 103.1,106.3 103.1,106.3 108.2,121.8 112.3,133.7 115.2,142.0 115.2,142.0 117.0,146.7 118.7,151.0 120.4,155.0 122.0,158.7 122.0,158.7 123.3,161.4 124.5,163.9 125.7,166.2 126.9,168.3 128.0,170.2 128.0,170.2 129.4,172.3 130.8,174.2 132.2,175.8 133.6,177.2 133.6,177.2 135.5,178.8 137.4,180.0 139.3,180.7 139.3,180.7 141.2,181.0 143.0,180.9 144.9,180.3 144.9,180.3 146.8,179.3 148.7,177.9 150.6,176.0 150.6,176.0 152.0,174.4 153.4,172.6 154.8,170.5 156.2,168.2 156.2,168.2 157.3,166.2 158.5,164.0 159.7,161.5 160.9,158.9 162.2,156.0 162.2,156.0 164.4,150.7 166.8,144.5 169.4,137.5 169.4,137.5 172.1,129.9 174.8,122.0 177.5,113.9 181.5,101.5" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        <g id="y" class="port">
            <polygon points="201.5,91.5 221.5,101.5 201.5,111.5" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00007F" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```